# Issue with uploading website to hosting

Tags: javascript, jquery, hosting, web-hosting

I tried uploading my website to the free 000webhosting service. My website loads fine locally, but when uploading it through FileZilla and reloading the page I get an error that says "The jQuery library must be included before the smoothscroll.js file.  The plugin will not work properly."
I have a smooth scrolling javascript file and some jquery in my code that I got from somebody else. Does anybody have any idea why my website loads fine locally, but the smooth scrolling doesn't load when uploading my site to a host? And yes, the jquery is before the javascript.

Comment: And do the developer tools that nowadays all browsers conveniently provide under F12 actually **confirm** that jquery's file got loaded?

Comment: So I viewed the page source and the jquery was there. I also realized that the font was different between the locally hosted version versus the hosted version. Any other ideas since the jquery was loaded?

Comment: nonono, not the source, it's pretty obvious that that won't have changed. Check out the "network" tab in developer tools, reload the page and check whether **all** files get properly loaded/found.

Answer (score 0):

**Try** to check for your problem:

- The files don't exist on the server at all at that path
- You moved the files but didn't change the path in index.html
- You changed the path in index.html but didn't move the files there

Comment: But it loads fine locally. I'm not sure I understand what your trying to suggest me to do. I don't think any of the above apply to me, but thanks for trying. Do you have other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the files of the particular plugin on the hosting server.
There must be some files that are missing or not uploaded completely.